# use for loop result as class name

Tags: javascript

I want to learn JavaScript and got stuck on some code.

I make a array en show the results in a div with fixed id, but i want the class name to be the name of the array result.

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
document.write("<div id=fruit>" + fruits[i] + "</div>") ;  
document.getElementById("fruit").className = fruits[i];
}
```

This is the result i get

```
<div id="fruit" class="Mango">Banana</div>
<div id="fruit">Orange</div>
<div id="fruit">Apple</div>
<div id="fruit">Mango</div>
```

Only the first div gets a class but with the wrong arry result.

I searched for hours and can not get it to work.
Would be nice if someone point me to the right info on what i do wrong.

Comment: `id` attribute is used to specify a unique id. Do not put the same id multiple times.
And Because `id` is to specify a unique id, `document.getElementById` returns the first found item. that's the reason why you get the result. Your code override class name of the first element  over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because at `document.getElementById("fruit").className = fruits[i];` you selected an element by id and it only returns 1 element, "the first occurrence" as you are expected to use unique ID per element.

You can simply do something like this:

```js
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
document.write("<div id='"+fruits[i]+"-fruit' class='"+fruits[i]+"'>" + fruits[i] + "</div>") ;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes thanks that works perfect, I player around with the fruits[1]  in the id and class tags but i needed to add + to it, Now i understand.  Only how come the -fruits can be outside the "" of the div id ?

Comment: sorry, ive edited the code so it would make more sensible. so if you notice, the id name and class name are inside single quotes `'`, I used them so it would not conflict with the  the double quotes `"` I used to enclose the string expression. hope that makes sense.

Comment: hey, awesome, now i makes sence to me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: no problem, if you can accept the answer so it would help other with similar issue. ty

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of id is that it identifies a single element in the document. In your case the divs share id and consequently `getElementById` achieves the last one, the solution would be to make each id unique for each element, for example fruit-0, fruit-1, ... according to the current index of the iteration

Javascript as you will see is a very versatile programming language, there exist for example `for..of` that allows you to iterate over elements of an array or or similar in a simpler way, many programmers use this method because it is very friendly and the truth be told we write less

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

for (const [index, fruit] of fruits.entries()) {
  const element = `<div id="fruit-${index}" class="${fruit}">${fruit}</div>`;

  console.log(element);
}
```

About `.entries()`, is used in the example because `for..of` does not have a way to check the current index in iteration, as in your case you can use `.entries()` which allows you to get the id and value of the current array, these are passed to `[index, value]` which you then use in the iteration